# Pandas datframe excel errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I've been debugging this script and continue to get the following error

```
'python3 report_generator_1_5_3.py
```

Opening spreadsheet from .\CVB Logix Firmware-Test Run-20210430.xls...

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\report_generator_1_5_3.py", line 542, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\report_generator_1_5_3.py", line 506, in main
[all_data,suite_list] = openSpreadsheet()
File "C:\Users\report_generator_1_5_3.py", line 102, in openSpreadsheet
all_data = pd.read_excel(workbook_name, 1 ,usecols=['Name','Test Stand','Report Location', 'Output Location', 'Status',
File'
```

Here is some of the code

```
 def openSpreadsheet():
 93     '''Opens spreadsheet generated by qTest, reorders the columns 
 94     and sorts rows by test name'''
 96     #File name of today's regression results
 97     workbook_name = today.strftime('.\Regression\CVB Logix Firmware-Test Run-%Y%m%d.xls')
 98     print(f'Opening spreadsheet from {workbook_name}...\n')
 99 
100     #Turns regression data into dataframe
101     all_data = pd.read_excel(workbook_name, 1 ,usecols=['Name','Test Stand','Report Location', 'Output Lo    cation', 'Status',
102                             'Link to Execution Artifacts', 'Test Case Id','Id', 'Test Case Version',
103                             'Executed Start','Executed End','Execution State','Test 
Suite', 'Test Cycle',     'Test Case Automation Metadata: Script Name'],index=False)'
```

Any assistance?

Comment: Is the above the entire error traceback report?, If not please post the entire report.

Comment: Here is more:                                                                                                                      .. .all_data = pd.read_excel(workbook_name, 1 ,usecols=['Name','Test Stand','Report Location', 'Output Location', 'Status', 'Link to Execution Artifacts', 'Test Case id', 'id', 'Test Case Version', 'Executed Start', 'Executed End', 'Executed State', 'Test Suite', 'Test Cycle', 'Test Case Automation Metadata: Script Name'],index_col=False)
  File "C:\Users\.Python.3.9\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Users\RDancy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

Comment: File "C:\Users\RDancy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1071, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Users\RDancy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 949, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(

Comment: File "C:\Users\RDancy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 949, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\RDancy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 651, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\Regression\\CVB Logix Firmware-Test Run-20210430.xls'

Comment: This is entire traceback output